# Problem trying to position: fixed on a grid row

Tags: php, html, css, css-grid

Im trying to do that: get 3 consecutives rows of a grid being "fixed;" but Im having problems that idk. Heres my code:

```
.main-container {
  
    display:grid;
    background-color:#e0e0e0;
    grid-template-columns: 50% 50%;
    box-sizing:border-box;
        z-index:-1;
  
}
.main-container > * {
   text-align:center;
    display:flex;
    justify-content:center;
    align-items:center;
    
  
}
.main-container div {
    color:black;
    border: px solid black;
    
}
.main-container video {
    display:block;

    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    
    /* Scale video to container size */
   object-fit: cover;
   object-position: center;
    z-index:10000;   
}
.main-container h4 {
    color:#edbd87;
}

.item1{
    grid-column: 1 / 3;
    background-color: green;
    height:1080px;

}
.item2{
    right:0;
    left:0;
    top:300px;
    bottom:0;
    position:absolute;
    grid-column: 1 / 3;
    display:inline-block;
    z-index:1000000;
}

.item3{
    background:#e0e0e0;
    grid-column: 1 / 3;
    height:40vh;
    border-bottom:1px solid black;
        
}

.item4 {
    padding:30px;
   z-index:10;
    width:100%;
    height:800px;
}
.item4 img{
    padding:15px;
    justify-self:center;
    
     display:block;
    width:90%;
    height:80%;
    
    /* Scale video to container size */
   object-fit: cover;
   object-position: center;
    border-radius: 80px 20px;
    z-index:10;
}
.item5{
    padding:40px;
    width:100%;
    display: inline;
    z-index:9;
}
.item5 *{
    padding:20px;
    font-weight:bold;
    font-size: 300%;
}
.item5 p{
    margin-top:30px;
    padding:40px;
    font-weight:bold;
    font-size: 180%;
}
.item5 h4{
    margin-top:40px;
    font-weight:bold;
    font-size: 640%;
}


<?php get_header(); ?>

<div class="main-container">

        <div class="item1">
            <video id="vid" src="http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/themes/twentytwentyone-child/img/coffee1.mp4" width="1920" height="1080" autoplay loop muted type="video/mp4"> </video>
        </div> 
        <div class="item2">
            <p style="font-size:50px; color:white;"> Join Us! </P>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-warning" style="font-family:forum; font-weight:bold; background-color:transparent; border-radius: 3px; color:yellow; font-size:50px; border: 2px solid yellow;">Warning</button>
        </div>
        <div class="item3">
            <img src="http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/themes/twentytwentyone-child/img/logo.png" />
        </div>
        <div class="item4">
        <img src="http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/themes/twentytwentyone-child/img/arvan2.jpg" />
        </div>
        <div class="item5">
            <h4>WHO WE ARE?</h4>
        <p>
            ArvanJobs is above all peace of mind. It is a new way 
            of working, of traveling, of training, of advancing in 
            your career. Whether you are a company looking for 
            workers or you are looking for a new job 
            opportunity, ArvanJobs will always be by your side, 
            selecting the best workers and the best companies 
            that will boost your career.
        </p>
            </div>      
        <div class="item6">
        <h4>WHY WORK WITH US?</h4>
        <p>
            For our personal treatment, our advice, and above 
            all for our experience working in hotels in 
            numerous countries.
            Because we know how difficult it is to take that step 
            of daring to work in a foreign country. Because we 
            know how hard it is to find the right staff.
        </p>
        </div>
        <div class="item7">
            <img src="http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/themes/twentytwentyone-child/img/arvan4.jpg">
        </div>
        <div class="item8">
            <h4>HOW WE WORK?</h4>
            <p>
All candidates are interviewed by staff who have 
worked in hotels, not offices
The same happens with our clients who have to 
satisfy a series of criteria and guarantees for the 
worker to work with us.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="item9">9</div>
        <div class="item10">10</div>
        
        
</div>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

I want to fix .item4 and .item5 (they are in a row with 2 columns) and triplicate the row to be the same (with diff content) 3 times. And I want all of the 3 rows being fix.
The problem is when i put the position fixed in any of the .items the thing goes crazy.

I upload a image to clarify myself, sry about:
[image]

There u can see the 3 rows, I want the 3 rows being fixed, or at least the images being fixed for when I scroll down, the 2nd row will cover the 1st, and then the 3rd will cover the 2nd. I like this "diapositive" effect.

Comment: That's what `position:fixed` does... it fixes elements in relation to the viewport not any grid.

Comment: then the only solution is that I have to adjust manually the fixed content to the grid cell? The problem that idk its when i put position:fixed usually it dissapears haha Ive tried to put z-index:99999999 but still cant see where it go.

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to achieve here. Clarification and a design image would be useful here.

Comment: Ive just edited my post with a image, sry if i didnt be enough clear.

Comment: `position:sticky` might be a better option here.

Comment: If the content of the row is fixed, when i scroll down the image and the text didnt scroll down, they will stay fixed, and the "effect" its like the 2nd row is covering the 1st with the scroll down. Sry about my bad english haha I am more clear now?

Comment: Ive tried the position:sticky too but the same: when i put that to an .item img {} it just dissapears doesnt matter the z-index that i put. I think there's a problem with the z-index and positioned objects but I cant fix or sticky that image anyway.

Comment: You don't put it on the image, you put it on the row item

Comment: If i put it to the ".item{}" didnt do any, if i put it to the  ".item img {}" dissapears.

Comment: You are right! at the .item, but i forgot to put the top:0; it appears! haha Now i have to adjust manualy I understand, coz it has no reference at all right?

Comment: Please share more details. Is this really a PHP problem?

Answer (score -1):

I tried some solutions, you can use this one:
when I position the element in the grid to fix, I make a new empty element with the same width and height, and the problem is solved.